# String formatting in Oracle (PL/)SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Modern programming languages allows the developer to create strings with placeholders and replaced the correct values with a function/method usually called `format`. Sometimes, it looks like this:

```
"Hi {0}! How are you?".format('John');
```

Is there any function in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL with the same behavior? Or what's the best practice here?

Comment: Same question but for javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[utl_lms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_lms.htm#BABGHIFE) package, and specifically `format_message()` procedure of that package can be used to format a string.

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_lms.format_message('Hi %s! How are you %s?.'
                                             , 'John'
                                             , 'John'
                                             )
                       );
end;
```

Result:

```
Hi John! How are you John?.
```

It should be noted that:

1. It works only within a PLS/SQL block, not SQL.
2. You should provide substituting value for every substituted special character (`%s` for string, `%d` for numbers) even if they are the same.